# How to Export Angular Unit Test Results to SonarQube?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, karma-coverage

I am using SonarQube Version 8.9.2 (build 46101) and
I want to export the test results to the SonarQube portal under my project.

I was able to push the result of the scan including the code coverage to the SonarQube portal but I am not able to push\export the Unit test result of my Angular code.
The build is successful but still the Unit test result are not exported. I still see - above Unit Tests like below,

[image]

I am able to generate the XML file in Generic Test Execution format as mentioned in SonarQube documentation like below,

[image]

I am using the below Sonar properties in my Azure DevOps Classic UI pipeline,

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NextGen
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts,NextGen/src/Tools/**
sonar.tests=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NextGen/src
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.ts.tslint.configpath=tslint.json
sonar.typescript.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/typings.d.ts,**/main.ts,**/environments/environment*.ts,**/*routing.module.ts
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=NextGen/coverage/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=NextGen\src\testresults\unittest\unit-test-result.xml
sonar.buildbreaker.skip=true
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help me to resolve this last thing pending for me on how to export the unit test result to SonarQube.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sonar-project.properties` seems to be good. You may add :

- sonar.projectKey
- sonar.projectName
- sonar.projectVersion
- sonar.language=ts

If you use Karma, you have to add `karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter` dependency in `package.json` and to add something in `karma.config.js` :

```
...
plugins: [
...
   require("karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter"),
...
],
sonarQubeUnitReporter: {
    sonarQubeVersion: "LATEST",
    outputFile: "NextGen\src\testresults\unittest\unit-test-result.xml",
    overrideTestDescription: true,
    testPaths: ["$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NextGen/src"],
    testFilePattern: ".spec.ts",
    useBrowserName: false,
},
reporters: ["sonarqubeUnit"],
...
```

Comment: Also added below in sonar-project.properties and it worked

sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=NextGen/src/testresults/unittest/unit-test-result.xml

Answer (score 0):

On [the official community site](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-generate-reports-for-apex-c-c-objective-c-go-js-ts-and-python/9687) for JS/TS languages following can be found:

> **JavaScript/TypeScript**
>
> Test Data Converters to Generic Test Data format
>
> for Jest [jest-sonar-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-sonar-reporter)
>
> for Karma [karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter)